# Subprocess in python2 returns error

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, libots

I am trying to input the text to the `ots` summerizer on Ubuntu. I am using the python2 `subprocess` library. But consistently getting the following error:

```
text = "the shards that cut me the deepest were the ones that intended to cut , obama to melania trump as first lady 's largest public appearance since the 2016 election - speaking in front of more than 8,000 people at the women 's foundation of colorado 's 30th anniversary celebration - and she touched on personal attacks that she faced again and again"
>>> sum = subprocess.check_output('ots --ratio=30 <' + text)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 567, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1343, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 36] File name too long
```

Even I have read that the `ots` takes input from the file or the `stdin`. Hence I tried to put input as:

```
sum = subprocess.check_output(['echo',text,'> stdin'])
```

But getting the following output:

```
"the shards that cut me the deepest were the ones that intended to cut , obama to melania trump as first lady 's largest public appearance since the 2016 election - speaking in front of more than 8,000 people at the women 's foundation of colorado 's 30th anniversary celebration - and she touched on personal attacks that she faced again and again > stdin\n"
```

But it is not what I am trying to achieve. I just want to input the text to the `ots` library using the `subprocess` of python. Is theer a way to do that and get the summary from the `ots` faster? Kindly, help me.

Comment: `'ots --ratio=30 <' + text` uses the string in `text` as a file name to read from. I don't know `ots`, maybe it has a way to accept a string from the command line. If not, you could pass it a command line string as if it were coming from a file by using a [here string](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html): `'ots --ratio=30 <<<' + text`, but you'll have to tell `subprocess` to use `bash` instead of `sh` since `sh` doesn't support here strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need the `|` pipe operator.

```
sum = subprocess.check_output('echo {} | ots --ratio=30'.format(text), shell=True)
```

The `<` symbol in bash is used take input from another stream.

Comment: getting the following error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 567, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1343, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
`

Comment: @JafferWilson Try now? I think I missed `shell=True`